# Callable result can't be assigned to array

Tags: php

I want to add a dog object to an array and `var_dump` it after but the array stays empty. Am I breaking some rule of the OOP concept or something?

```
class Dog {

    public $name;
    public $bread;

}

class MyClass {

    public $dogArr = [];

    public function __construct( $key , callable $callback ) {
        $dogArr[$key] = $callback ();
    }

}

public function actionTest() {

    $newDog = new \backend\components\MyClass ( "first" , function () {
        $dog = new \backend\components\Dog();
        $dog->name = "Archi";
        $dog->bread = "Pomeran";
        return $dog;
    } );

    var_dump ( $newDog->dogArr );
}
```

Comment: There isn't an easy way to assure that a variable is the one you are expecting to update. A unit test, (or static analysis) will help enormously though and would fail quickly in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a small change to your `MyClass` constructor:

Change:

```
$dogArr[$key] = $callback();
```

to

```
$this->dogArr[$key] = $callback();
```

Otherwise you're just setting a value in a local variable, rather than the class property.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if u want to access the property of class u have to use self or $this operator

Following should work

```
class Dog
{
    public $name;
    public $bread;
}

class MyClass
{
        public $dogArr = [];

        public function __construct($key, callable $callback){
            $this->dogArr[$key] = $callback();
        }
}

public function actionTest(){

     $newDog = new \backend\components\MyClass("first", function (){
           $dog = new \backend\components\Dog();
           $dog->name = "Archi";
           $dog->bread = "Pomeran";
           return $dog;
        });

        var_dump($newDog->dogArr);

}

actionTest();
```